# Copy recursively a directory excluding a subdirectory and ITS CONTENT

Tags: powershell

I found solutions, but this solutions don't exclude the content of the subdirectories excluded.

I want copy recursively a directory to another location, but excluding the subdirectory "Videos" and its content.
The next command finish, but no exclude the subdirectory "Videos" and its content.

```
# PowerShell version: 4.0
# This command copy recursively the directory "J:\All" to "J:\Users\John\Desktop\my_backup", excluding "J:\All\Videos"
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path ("J:\All" | ? { $_.FullName -NotMatch ("^J:\\All\\Videos") }) "J:\Users\John\Desktop\my_backup"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RoboCopy is a better solution here. See https://superuser.com/questions/482112/using-robocopy-and-excluding-multiple-directories

```
robocopy J:\All J:\Users\John\Desktop\my_backup /MIR /XD j:\all\videos
```

Comment: Perfect! But if I want conserve the folder "All"? The content of "All" is copied to "my_backup", and I want copy "All" to "my_backup".

Comment: Change your destination to `J:\Users\John\Desktop\my_backup\All`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Source = 'J:\All'
$Destination = 'J:\Users\John\Desktop\my_backup\'
$Exclude = 'J:\All\Videos'

Get-Childitem -Recurse -Path $Source | 
Where-Object  { $Exclude -notcontains $_.Directory } |
foreach {
 $TrimmedPath = ($_.fullname -replace [regex]::escape($Source)).trim('\') |
 copy-item  -Destination "$($Destination.Trim('\'))\$TrimmedPath"
}
```

Comment: This solution copy all sub,sub,sub...directories (and without files) to my_backup. I want conserve my filesystem, and behind the directories, more directories...

Comment: I do not understand the reply.

Comment: In a small copy (directory), the script works.
In a big copy, no, and the folders hasn't content. In addition, the subdirectory of a Videos, is empty (in my_backup).

Comment: Updated the answer.  See if that does what you want.